# Waiting for external events in Durable Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, c#-2.0, .net-core-3.1, azure-durable-functions

I have an Orchestrator function as follows:

```
[FunctionName("O_OrchestratorFunction)]
        public async Task<object> Process(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
            await context.CallActivityAsync("A_SendApprovalRequestEmail", "email");

            var _approvalResult = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<string>("ApprovalResult");

            if (_approvalResult == "Approved")
            {
                await context.CallActivityAsync("A_ResumeJobSync", "email");
            }
            else
            {
                await context.CallActivityAsync("A_PauseJobSync", "email");
            }
            return _approvalResult;
        }
    }
```

Here is my A_SendApprovalRequestEmail Activiy function:

```
    [FunctionName("A_SendApprovalRequestEmail")]
    public async Task Run([ActivityTrigger] string job, TraceWriter log)
    {
            var functionAddress = $"http://localhost:7071/api/";
            var approvedLink = functionAddress + "approve?id=MYID";
            var rejectedLink = functionAddress + "reject?id=MYID";
            var content = $"{approvedLink}  {rejectedLink}";
            await _mailRepository.SendMail("Subject", content, "<recipient-address>");
            log.Info($"Requesting approval for {job}");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
```

How do I modify this code to connect 2 links to the orchestrator - one for Approve and one for Reject (that returns the result ‘Approved’ or ‘Rejected’)?

UPDATE:

I have added 2 starter functions:

```
        [FunctionName("Approve")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Approve(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client)
        {
            string orchestratorId = req.Query["id"];                 
            log.LogInformation($"Approval request for {orchestratorId}"); 
            var status = await client.GetStatusAsync(orchestratorId);
            if (status == null || status.RuntimeStatus != OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running)
                return new NotFoundResult();

            await client.RaiseEventAsync(orchestratorId, "ApprovalResult", "Approve");

            return new OkObjectResult("Approval successfull");
        }

        [FunctionName("Reject")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Reject(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
           [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client)
        {
            string orchestratorId = req.Query["id"];

            log.LogInformation($"Reject request for {orchestratorId}");

            var status = await client.GetStatusAsync(orchestratorId);

            if (status == null || status.RuntimeStatus != OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running)
                return new NotFoundResult();


            await client.RaiseEventAsync(orchestratorId, "ApprovalResult", "Reject");

            return new OkObjectResult("Rejected");
        }
```

This is what I see on clicking Approve/Reject link:

[image]

[image]

On putting breakpoint at

```
var status = await client.GetStatusAsync(orchestratorId);
```

I see status as null.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create 2 HTTP functions for reject and approve just as you created your starter function with the IDurableOrchestratorClient. These functions would need to receive some way to get the unique orchestratorid that was used to start the orchestration. This is stored in the context.InstanceId property in the orchestrator. The easiest way is just to send this in the query [www.test.com/api/approve?id=myid](http://www.test.com/api/approve?id=myid) but there are other solutions where you map the query value to which orchestrator through e.g DB or jwt token. This HTTP triggered function is what link will be in your email. The HTTP triggerd function can then with this id raise events in the orchestrator.

```
        [FunctionName("Approve")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Approve(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
           [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client)
        {
            // Takes the id parameter in the url e.g. www.test.com/api/approve?id=SomeID would return SomeID
            string orchestratorId = req.Query["id"];

            log.LogInformation($"Approval request for {orchestratorId}");

            // Makes sure there is a running instance with this orchestrator 
            var status = await client.GetStatusAsync(orchestratorId);
            if (status == null || status.RuntimeStatus != OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running)
                return new NotFoundResult();

            //Raises event ApprovalResult with data Approve
            await client.RaiseEventAsync(orchestratorId, "ApprovalResult", "Approve");

            return new OkObjectResult("Approval successfull");
        }

        [FunctionName("Reject")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Reject(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
           [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client)
        {
            string orchestratorId = req.Query["id"];

            log.LogInformation($"Reject request for {orchestratorId}");

            var status = await client.GetStatusAsync(orchestratorId);

            if (status == null || status.RuntimeStatus != OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running)
                return new NotFoundResult();


            await client.RaiseEventAsync(orchestratorId, "ApprovalResult", "Reject");

            return new OkObjectResult("Rejected");
        }

[FunctionName("O_OrchestratorFunction)]
        public async Task<object> Process(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
           TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
           DateTime deadline = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(timeout);
           using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
           {
            await context.CallActivityAsync("A_SendApprovalRequestEmail", new Tuple<string,string>("email", context.InstanceId));
            Task timeoutTask = context.CreateTimer(deadline, cts.Token);

            var approvalTask = context.WaitForExternalEvent<string("ApprovalResult");
            Task task = await Task.WhenAny(activityTask, timeoutTask);
            if (task == approvalTask)
            {
                cts.cancel();
                if(task.Result == "Approve")
                   await context.CallActivityAsync("A_ResumeJobSync", "email");
                else 
                    await context.CallActivityAsync("A_PauseJobSync", "email");
            }
            else
            {
                // Code for timeout scenario (maybe execute A_PauseJobSync)
            }
            return _approvalResult;
        }
    }
}

[FunctionName("A_SendApprovalRequestEmail")]
    public async Task Run([ActivityTrigger] Tuple<string, string> data, TraceWriter log)
    { // data.Item1 = "email" & data.Item2 = context.InstanceId
            var functionAddress = $"http://localhost:7071/api/";
            var approvedLink = functionAddress + $"approve?id={data.Item2}";
            var rejectedLink = functionAddress + $"reject?id={data.Item2}";
            var content = $"{approvedLink}  {rejectedLink}";
            await _mailRepository.SendMail("Subject", content, "<recipient-address>");
            log.Info($"Requesting approval for {job}");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
```

Here are the two HTTP triggered functions you can use as approve and reject functions and you would then in your content in the email link to [www.myfuncapp.com/api/approve?id=MYID](http://www.myfuncapp.com/api/approve?id=MYID) when someone clicks that link the approve function would run and raise event ApprovalResult with data Approve.

Comment: Thank you! My question is regarding how to connect link to orchestrator (updated question). Few questions-is the Approve function in your code a starter function? What does this comment indicate (  // Parse query parameter). Could you please provide the code? Should I create 2 new functions - one for Approve and one for Reject? Could you please clarify that? Can I use the link  https://www.test.com/api/approve?id=12345 as approval link which on clicking returns ’Approve’? What about rejection link that returns ‘Not Approved’? Please clarify the same.

Comment: Also, could you please show an example of Approve and Reject functions that expect some parameter e.g. id of orchestrator? Thank you!

Comment: @user989988 I have updated the answer to only answer your question and have tried to explain as best i can. But to answer your questions. Approve function is the same as the starter. The line after the comment is what parses the URL and receives the InstanceId in the orchestrator to know which orchestrator to approve since there could be many orchestrators waiting for the event. Yes create two functions (it is possible to just create one and in the link instead have test.com/api/raise?id=myid&type=approve) Dont be afraid to ask any questions for clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and reach out to you if I have more questions. 1 question - what should be the domain of the links http://www.myfuncapp.com/api/approve?id=MYID? Could you please clarify that?

Comment: @user989988 Since the url is meant to call the approve function you have created it will be the same as the function app domain[s]. During local testing this domain would normally be http://localhost:7071 and when you have deployed the function to azure it will look something like https://MyFuncApp.azurewebsites.net as default and if you own a custom domain it is possible to configure for that too.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my code in the question. Could you please let me know if my A_SendApprovalRequestEmail function looks correct? How do I pass orchestratorId (MYID) in the links? I see status as null after line await client.GetStatusAsync(orchestratorId);

Comment: @user989988 I have updated my answer on one way to get the correct id to the activity. It should be the same as context.instanceId which has to be passed to to the activity. Since you already had a parameter string job i used a tuple but if that string isnt necessary it can be substituted and only pass the context.InstanceId instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. 2 questions - 1) After the user clicks Approve/Reject link, I need to execute some code. Should that be a part of Approve/Reject starter functions or should that be a part of Activity functions in my code - A_ResumeJobSync & A_PauseJobSync. 2) When an email is sent, is there a way to verify that the user who clicked the Approve/Reject link is the right user (only if the user is valid, allow the user to Approve/Reject link)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228725/discussion-between-bjorne-and-user989988).